# Table synchronication in SQL server

Tags: sql-server

I have two tables in 2 different databases and I need to keep them in sync, i.e. any insert table A should be sync in table B and vice versa.
As both of the tables gets individual inserts therefore using a trigger for sync could end up in a recursive loop. What is the best way I could use to sync these two tables?

Comment: And what about DELETEs and UPDATEs?

Comment: The best way would be to keep only one table, and reference it with updatable views in both databases.

Comment: You can also use a trigger and procedure to keep them in sync

Comment: why do you need this? It sounds like a recipe for trouble. Try and have a single source of the truth. What is stopping you just using one single database?